# Nginx Load-Balancer Does Not Load React Site

Tags: reactjs, nginx, load-balancing

I have the following website which is a React built site. I have an nginx load-balance site with two backend servers. The individual servers work perfectly but when behind the load-balancers the site rarely load and looking at the browser dev tools there are a ton of 404 Not Found errors:

https://junoscan.skynetexplorers.com

I don't understand why the sites does not load. Sometimes a browser will start working properly. For example, currently Brave Browser does not work on my desktop but started working on my cell phone. What is happening? How do I fix this behavior?

```
##
# Set Rate Limiting (DDoS protection)
##

        limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_zone:10m rate=5r/s;


# This is the internal server behind the proxy
        upstream bdipper_node {
          least_conn;

          server cluster.provider-0.prod.sjc1.akash.pub:31375;
          server cluster.provider-2.prod.ewr1.akash.pub:31639;
        }

        map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
          default upgrade;
          '' close;
        }

# This is the public facing listening server AND configures SSL for the website
        server {

          root /_next/static/chunks;
          sendfile on;
          tcp_nopush on;
          sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
          tcp_nodelay on;
          keepalive_timeout 65;

          listen 443 ssl;

          location / {

            limit_req zone=req_zone burst=20 nodelay;

            proxy_pass http://bdipper_node/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:443;
          }
        }

# This redirect http to https
        server  {
          listen 80 ;
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
```